# Access violation when filling the char* array

Tags: c, access-violation

I've written a code in c:

```
const char *str[125000]; 
float k[125000];
long n;
char string[20];
int i;
scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    scanf("%s%f",&string,&k[i]);
    p=p/k[i];
    str[i]=_strdup(string);
    }
```

At this point everything's perfect. The array gets filled even if the n=100000; However if I change

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
```

to

```
for (i=n;i>0;i--)
```

i get the "Access violation" error. I've got no idea why is this happening so I'm asking for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is like one line different than your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676383/runtime-error-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C the size of n go from 0 to n - 1. So your loop should be

```
for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
```

You get an error because you are trying to access memory out of bounds of that array.

Comment: Wow, it did work. Thanks a lot. But I still don't get it. Even if the loop goes from n to 1, why would that matter, considering that the array's size is 125000 and n<=100000?

Comment: @DannyPhantom I don't know what was your test code, show the sscce.

Comment: `1
vsync 10`
that's the simplest test code which was failing.

Comment: I don't know what that `1 vsync 10` means.

Comment: @DannyPhantom I just noticed that `const char *str[125000]; ` and `scanf("%s%f",&string` wont work.

Answer (score 2):

When reading a character string using `%s` you should not pass the address of the string, instead simply pass the string: `scanf("%s%f",string,&k[i]);`.

Comment: @Chad I am not sure I understand your comment but the way OP reads the value of k[i] seems ok to me.

Comment: @DannyPhantom this is only one of your errors it seems. Also take a look at this.'s answer